# Make all row-entries in a column hyperlinks (Excel file production in R)

Tags: r, excel, hyperlink

Many people use Excel and exporting into xlsx is unfortunately important.
I want to produce "user friendly data outputs" that have hyperlinks.

How can I produce in R an excel file with 2 columns where the first column will be a hyperlinked (the desired link is specified in the third column).  (this is all on demo data)

(in my read dataset and output file,I need about 10 such columns "hyperlink enhanced").
It has to be an excel! HTML will not cut it! (data set is 20k rows and the browser will freeze and scrolling and column freezing is important)

See sample data here:

```
library(dplyr)
df<-select(iris,Species,Sepal.Length)
library(stringr)
df$hyperlink <-str_c('http://species.org/',df$Species)

> df[49:54,]
      Species Sepal.Length                     hyperlink
49     setosa          5.3     http://species.org/setosa
50     setosa          5.0     http://species.org/setosa
51 versicolor          7.0 http://species.org/versicolor
52 versicolor          6.4 http://species.org/versicolor
53 versicolor          6.9 http://species.org/versicolor
54 versicolor          5.5 http://species.org/versicolor
```

EDIT:
Ideally, the code would allow making any column in a data.frame a link that is specified by a formula (see the formula in the code where I use the function str_c ). Assume the df has 20+ columns and manually composing it again (for the sake of xlsx should be best avoided).

Solution in xlxs is fine, but potentially looking into other packages (or doing it in Python) is also an option.

It should look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a method in the `xlsx` package that adds hyperlinks to cells. Here is how you would add hyperlinks using a for loop.

If anyone else knows how to do this without the usage of a for loop (i.e. adding an entire vector as a column of cells) that would be a bit more efficient.

```
library(xlsx)
wb <- createWorkbook()
sheet1 <- createSheet(wb, "Sheet1")
rows <- createRow(sheet1, seq_along(df$hyperlink)) 
cells <- createCell(rows, colIndex=1:2) # 2 columns
for (i in seq_along(cells[,1])){
  col1 <- cells[[i,1]]
  setCellValue(col1, df$Species[i])
  addHyperlink(col1,df$hyperlink[i])
  col2 <- cells[[i,2]]
  setCellValue(col2,df$Sepal.Length[[i]])
}
saveWorkbook(wb, file="workbook.xlsx") # Add your file path here
```

[image]

Comment: It is on the right path. The result should have 2 columns only. so column one value should be     setCellValue(col1,df$Species) and that col1 should have the link in column 3; ALso, col2 should be Sepal.Length

Comment: @userJT Edited to reflect proper column values and added a screenshot.